# Allowance and transfer tokens from contract B using contract A to user address X

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have deployed contract A.
Now I am creating gateway contract B and I want to send some tokens of contract A to user address X using owner address.
Worth to mention that contract A owner is the same as contract B.
I do the following

```
contract A is Ownable { // this one already deployed by owner
  constructor() {
    owner = msg.sender; // owner address is 0x123
    approve(msg.sender, totalSupply); // let's approve all tokens for owner
  }      

  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool) {
    require(value <= allowed[from][msg.sender], "Not allowed!");
    // let's skip other logic
  }
}    

contract B is Ownable { // gateway contract will be deployed and executed by same owner
  A contractA = ETC20(0x111);
  address payable X = 0x333;

  constructor() {
    owner = msg.sender; // owner address is 0x123
  }

  function giveAwayTokens(uint256 value) {
    contractA.transferFrom(owner, X, value);
  }
}
```

When I execute "giveAwayTokens" function from owner address (0x123), I get error "Not allowed!".
So I am a bit confused right now, because the allowance of owner from owner is max supply.
Or maybe the msg.sender is contractB itself?
Please enlighten me what I am doing wrong here, thank you

Comment: This example is incomplete because we do not know what `msg.sender` in in the constructor.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I've updated the example with owner set logic. So basically both contract owner is 0x123 address. Also, 0x123 executes the giveAwayTokens function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `ContractB` calls `ContractA`, the `msg.sender` in `ContractA` is `ContractB` address.

Based on the code and the error message, the `owner` (`0x123`) didn't allow `ContractB` to spend their tokens.

You need to set the value of `allowed[<owner>][<ContractB>]` to be at least the amount of tokens that you want to send.

Most likely you have an `approve()` function ([defined](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md#approve) in the token standard) that you can use. In the linked example, the caller of the function would be the `owner`, the `spender` would be the `ContractB` and the `value` would be any value equal or higher than the amount of tokens that you want to send (mind the decimals).

Comment: Thank you Petr, I'll try this out! I already marked your answer as correct one, because it must be, it's very logical!